# Python If(and) statement syntax error

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to make a simple console game in Python 2.7, where the user gets a dilemma and makes a decision by typing the number correlating to the option he wants to choose. This question is the main menu.

```
s = raw_input("Enter a number in the range 1 to %s\n> " % v
if (is_number(s) and s in q):           
    return s
```

I'm getting a "SyntaxError: Invalid syntax" from the if (is_number(s) and s in q) statemet when trying to run the program. It was working fine before i added the question.

This is my first real program.

Comment: Missing a close paren in the previous line: `s = raw_input("Enter a number in the range 1 to %s\n> " % v`

Comment: People, it's obviously someone taking its first steps with python, could we try to cool it with the downvotes and the close votes?

Comment: This person didn't willingly break the rules, they just haven't ever encountered a syntax error before.

Comment: There are several problems with your code: 1- you are missing a closing `)` as Steven said, 2- the parenthesis in the `if` statement are not needed, 3- the `is_number` function is not defined and neither is the `q`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a parentheses on the previous line:

```
s = raw_input("Enter a number in the range 1 to %s\n> " % v
#                                                    here--^
```